# QLikView VBScript create field in PivotTable

Tags: vb.net, excel, vbscript, pivot-table, qlikview

I create a Pivot Table with a VBScript in QLikView:

```
sub cleanUp()

    set sheet = ActiveDocument.Sheets("Summary")

    set summaryTable = sheet.CreatePivotTable

    summaryTable.addDimension "Product Group Desc"
    summaryTable.addDimension "Product Type Desc"
    summaryTable.addDimension "Product Sub Group Desc"
    summaryTable.addDimension "Country"
    summaryTable.addDimension "ZoneMgrName"

    summaryTable.addExpression "Sum({<[Fiscal Year]={$(vCurrentYear)}>}
                                                           [Sales Amount])"

    set props = summaryTable.getProperties
    set expr = props.Expressions.Item(0).Item(0).Data.ExpressionVisual

    expr.Label.v = "Expenses $(vCurrentYear)"
    expr.NumAdjust = 1    'center
    expr.LabelAdjust = 1    'center
    summaryTable.SetProperties props

end sub
```

In addition I would like to create new fields used as dimensions. These fields are not in my QLikView document so far. The value for these fields is linked to the value of other fields. Say I have a field Country in my Pivot Table. I would like to add a new Field "Area" which contains the name of the area which the country belongs to. So that the values for the field would be the return value of a function which returns the area for a given country.

Comment: I have used qlikview a lot in conjunction with VBA so I'm hoping I can help. What exactly is the question? The code works, but you want it to do more? I'm unsure what you desire.

Comment: Thanks! I want to create a New Field (a field not existing in the QLikView document), and create a Dimension in the Pivot Table based on this field: `summaryTable.addDimension "NewField"

Comment: @tannman357 I have to specify the values for the new field: the values are the return value of a function which takes as argument the value for another field. See my example with country and area.

Comment: How did you use VBA in conjonction with qlikView ? Using VBScript or another way ?

Comment: I always export whatever data it is FROM qlikview into excel and then manipulate it there with macros that I store in another sheet. If you want to make new fields, it's very easy to do once in excel.

Comment: You could create the new field and then have the program fill in the area back on and if statement for whatever country it is. Can you post example data with you desired result?

Comment: the goal of the project is to show that i can replicate all operations inside Qlikview without exporting to Excel

Comment: Ohhhh..... I don't know about this qlikview side of it man... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how your "lookup" data is accessed (whether it resides in your QlikView document, or is external), but you are free to add calculated dimensions to your pivot via the `addDimension` method. For example:

```
summaryTable.addDimension "=if(Country='France', 'EU', 'non-EU')"
```

You can use any normal expression that can return meaningful values for your dimension.

If you wish to name the dimension, you can use `addDimension`'s return value as follows:

```vbs
dimensionNum = summaryTable.addDimension("=if(Country='France', 'EU', 'non-EU')")

set tableProperties = summaryTable.getProperties

set calcDim = tableProperties.Dimensions.Item(dimensionNum-1)
calcDim.Title.v = "Area"

summaryTable.SetProperties tableProperties
```